# Understanding constructors and "this"

Tags: java, constructor, this

I'm learning constructors and I understand them for the most part, but I must not understand it enough. I also don't understand `this` fully. But this code below is supposed to use these constructors:

> default constructor, which will be used to fill the matrix with random doubles
>
> constructor which takes a File object, which points to a file
>   containing a matrix,
>
> constructor which takes a string, which contains the name of the file
>
> constructor which takes a value of type Matrix, and makes a copy of it
>
> constructor which takes a 2D array, and copies its values

And some more, along with a static multiply method. I am supposed to use the commands that are found in `main`. But I don't quite understand how using a String as the only parameter will do the constructor it's told to, and also the other ones like the default constructor that fills the array with random doubles. I think I should be using `this` more in my code, but I'm not quite sure.

I mainly just need to be able to set a matrix, fill m1 matrix with random doubles, do it again with m2 matrix, and then use the static multiply method to multiply them, then output the resulting matrix. Thank you.

(Just a heads up, I'm using a 3 by 3 matrix, originally I was supposed to set the size of the matrix to the one found in the text file, but I can also specify the size I want, which I am. And sorry for the messy code. It got all jumbled up while I was trying to figure this stuff out, and I'm afraid of altering it further.)

```
public class Matrix {

        double A[][] = new double[3][3]


        // Matrix file name
        public Matrix(String name) {
            this(new File(name));
        }

        // Matrix random fill
        public Matrix() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                this.A[i][j] = (min + Math.random() * (max - min));
        }

        // Matrix copy
        public Matrix(double[][] A) {
            private double[][] arrcopy = new double[3][3];
            private double[][] array = new double[3][3];
            array = A;

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; ++j) {
                    arrcopy[i][j] = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        // Set array from text file
        public Matrix(File a) {

            File f = a;
            Scanner inputStreamOne = null;

            try{
                inputStreamOne = new Scanner(f);
            }

            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.printf("Error\n");
            }

            double arrayOne[][] = new double[3][3];

            while(inputStreamOne.hasNextInt()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                    for(int j = 0; j < arrayOne[i].length; ++j){
                    arrayOne[i][j] = inputStreamOne.nextInt();
                    }
                }
            inputStreamOne.close();
            }
        }

        // Gets array in file from string name
        public Matrix(String a) {

            String inputOne = a;
            Scanner inputStreamOne = null;

            try{
                inputStreamOne = new Scanner(new File(inputOne));
            }

            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.printf("Error\n");
            }



            while(inputStreamOne.hasNextInt()){
                for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
                    for(int j = 0; j < arrayOne[i].length; ++j){
                    arrayOne[i][j] = inputStreamOne.nextInt();
                    }
                }
            inputStreamOne.close();
            }

        }

        public static multiply

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Matrix m = new Matrix("matrix1.txt");
            Matrix m2 = new Matrix("matrix2.txt");
            Matrix r = Matrix.multiply(m, m2);
            r.output(...);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you feel you need to make more use of `this` ?

Answer (score 0):

Within a constructor or a method `this` refers to the current object. Within a constructor, if you just use a bare `this` ( which is to say `this` without a `.method` after it ) then it refers to another constructor of the same object that has a different type signature.

Constructors, like any function in Java, can be overloaded. Which is to say, because of Java's type system you can have multiple functions that are of the same name so long as they have different type signatures.

```
class Foo {

    public Foo ( String arg ) {
        this(arg, "World");
    }

    public Foo ( String arg1, String arg2 ) {
        // do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    }

 }
```

In the above example, one constructor takes a single string and the other takes two. Java won't magically know what to do with the data passed into different constructors. What you have to do is write code in each method so that the resulting object is the same. ( Well technically you don't have to do that, but it's good form ( usually overloaded constructors are for setting default values or for the ease of use of other programmers ))

Comment: Okay, that did help a little bit, thank you! But, I'm only allowed to use the commands that are in `main` so the only constructor I can really call is the one that uses the String as an argument. Would I just call the random fill constructor from within the constructor I call in `main`?

Comment: Assuming all of your constructors are `public` then you can call any of them from main. The one that gets called is based on what arguments you pass in. So if you pass no arguments then then random fill one will be called.

Comment: Well, yes of course, I do understand that, and that is what I would, ideally, use. But my professor said that we should be able to write the program by just using what I already written in `main`. And that's where I have trouble. Because there is no constructor provided with no arguments. So, I'm restricted by what is called in `main` already, without adding anything more.(Except for changing the "..." in output method, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword refers to the current object in a constructor or a method, i.e. the object whose constructor or method is being called. Within a constructor, you can also use `this` to call another constructor in the class.

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html for a clear explanation from Java Tutorials.